# Is it possible to create grid view/list view with different width children?

Tags: android

I want to develop [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DWi1.png) type of layout. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I did this using a [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout). You can use any view. I have used textView as I needed only that. You may have to create a custom view and include it programmatically.

```
<com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout
            android:id="@+id/rquestion_fl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:tag="tagView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:tag="tagView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

 <!-- You can programmatically add View -->
```

Comment: Please give me the java code , to use FlowLayout as i am totally unknown about this...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Staggered Grid

Check the link below

http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/